# Memory error of fitting sklearn.KNN in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am fitting a [kNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) model in Ubuntu, Python, and sklearn with 32 GB DDR4 RAM.

I wan to load the model without fitting the model again, so I decided to dump the fitted model after fitting it.

The input is a large dataset, 1M+ rows, 1052 columns. (Most of columns are the dummy of categorical variables in [0,1].)

After the KNN fitted, I got a `Memory Error` when trying to dump the model with pickle.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 14)
knn = knn.fit(x,y)

import pickle
pickle.dump(knn, open('KNN.sav', 'wb'))
```

From the other post, the solution always to use higher specifications and RAM to solve it. I think it is not a good solution for the long run.

Updated questions : Any possible way to limit the model train use 26/32GB and left 6GB for Dumping? or any method to save the fitted model etc.

Comment: The only solution is more RAM. There is not enough memory on your machine to keep the model after training and open a file stream to persist model in a file.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is ram used 31.3 /32GB  and caused `Memory Error` when i Dump the model. Any possible way to limit the model train use 26/32GB and left 6GB for Dumping? or any method to save the fitted model etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a question - do you really need so huge training dataset? The idea is that the model maybe doesn't need whole dataset. A good [code example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html) from sklearn. Or use some of the cloud instance for working with such huge dataset.